# Solving Burger's equation $u_t + uu_x = 0$ using Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

So I want to solve

$$u_t + uu_x = 0$$

For the initial condition $u(x,0) = u_0(x)$ and work out the breaking points etc.

I attempted this in Mathematica but only got as far as solving the equation

```
 ClearAll[u, x, t];  
 pde = D[u[x, t], t] + D[u[x, t], x] == 0;  
 bc = u[0, t] == 0;  
 ic = u[x, 0] == x;  
 sol = DSolve[{pde, ic}, u[x, t],{x, t}]
```

How do I program mathematica to find the breaking time etc?

Comment: Did you try adding `u` there? as in `pde = D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x] == 0;`  I do not understand what you mean by `and work out the breaking points etc.`

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was I'm trying to calculate wave breaking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With corrected pde (see @Nasser's comment) `NDSolveValue` gives the complete solution

```
pde = D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t] D[u[x, t], x] == 0;
bc = u[0, t] == 0;
ic = u[x, 0] == x;
U = DSolveValue[{pde, ic}, u , {x, t}]    
(*U[x,t]=x/(1+t) *)
```